# 2021 - Unable to use custom fonts for emails in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, content-builder

I've been trying to import a custom font for MC emails.
I have followed the steps from this similar discussion:

[Custom font in Email content blocks](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235480/custom-font-in-email-content-blocks)

I have tried both ways - using SFTP and ContentBlock, and even pasted the Base64 code directly into the HTML.
But the solution seems to not work anymore.
I am encountering the error below:

*The HTML of this message is approximately 986.8 KB which exceeds the limit of some mail clients. These clients can show partially rendered messages. More Info*

Clicking 'More Info' will just redirect me to the documentation about Preview and Test Send, which is not that helpful:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_subscriber_preview_test_send.htm&type=5

Any idea on how to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so just to be clear this isn't an error its a warning message, have you tried sending the email to see how it loads/renders

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have tried testing it but the font has not changed.

Comment: Does the email client you are viewing it in support the font you are using? Gmail only supports two fonts for reference

Comment: Yes, I am using Roboto Regular. Sample usage `<span style="font-family:CUSTOM_FONT;">Sample Sample Sample</span>` and CSS is `@font-face {   
           font-family: CUSTOM_FONT;   
           src: url(data:font/ttf;charset=utf-8,base64,%%=ContentBlockByID(5700)=%%) format('truetype'); 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have successfully imported custom fonts just by adding the below code inside the style tag:

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;1,100;1,300;1,400&display=swap');`

Not using any Base64 code.