Poppins font is not displaying on mobile devices, its overwriting sans-serif/Times new roman in SFMC email
I want to display my email with Poppins font but on mobile device its overriding either sans-serif or times new roman.
Tried many things but same issue
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <head>
   
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
   
    <!--<![endif]-->
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
      
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:500,600,700" rel="stylesheet" />
   

 <style type="text/css">
    
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
   
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
       src: url('https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins'),
            url('fonts/Poppins-webfont.woff') format('woff');
      }  
      
      body {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
        font-family: Poppins !important;
      }

This is the css I am following.
Thank you for help!

Try using inline CSS as per the answer here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235480/custom-font-in-email-content-blocks

Thank you for sharing that, i have tried it but its still overwriting sans-serif in mobile view
