# How to upload google font or custom font to cloud landing page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, landing-page, font

On my cloud landing page, the fonts are using google fonts or adobe link font, the client wants to remove cdn or google font and wants the font to be imported in the marketing cloud itself, is it actually possible?

I did some research, but I don't think it has similar issue like mine. I will really appreciate if anyone can guide or giving step by step what to do.

Comment: Hope this helps...1) [Adding custom fonts to Salesforce CloudPage](https://pasankg.medium.com/adding-custom-fonts-to-salesforce-cloudpage-8075741ae3ef) ... 2) https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190896/upload-custom-font-on-marketing-cloud

Comment: @VishalKumarCV Hello Vishal, thanks for the link, I tried step by step, but the font doesn't seem to work, it transforms into default font. The terminal to encode the ttf, doesn;t seem to work, so I tried to use base64encode.org I just setup: "destination character set" to UTF-8, other than that I follow the link step. Do you know what is the possibility why the font doesn't work? I'm using an Oswald-bold font to test